# Crystal Reports - Link subreport parameter without field

Tags: crystal-reports, subreports

I have a subreport with several parameters.
The main report also has some parameters.

The subreport parameters are prompting when you run the main report...
All the parameters for both sub and main prompt at the same time.

Is there a way to get the subreport params to just prompt once you get to the subreport?

I have tried linking the subreport...
The problem is there are no fields to link to in the subreport.
The params for the subreport just point to start and end date formulas.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what the required parameters are for the subreport and how it is currently linked to the main report? What do you mean by, "...there are no fields to link to in the subreport"?

Answer (score 0):

Link the parameters of the sub report with parameters or fields of the main report... Coming to prompting the parameters when sub report is opened to the extent I know that is not possible but I would suggest you to try `Ondemand subreport` once.